# ASP MVC - WebSecurity - SimpleMemberShip - getting PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate by API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership, reset-password

I use *WebSecurity* API and *SimpleMemberShip* for serving accounts in my MVC4 app. One of its task is to reset the user password. *SimpleMemberShip* serves it through the method *GeneratePasswordResetToken()*. Besides it puts expiration date for the token.

I can not find the appropriate method for getting the expiration date (***PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate***).

Anybody found it?

Answer (score 0):

WebSecurity.ResetPassword return bool, and I solved the problem this way:

```
    public ActionResult Recover(Recover model)
    {
        var validateToken = WebSecurity.ResetPassword(model.token, model.Password);

        if (validateToken == true)
        {
            ViewBag.message = "password is changed.";
            return View();
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "password is not changed.");
        return View();
    }
```

see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.resetpassword(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: What do you mean you solved the problem? Which problem? I don't think it is the problem described in my question.